# How to use the function "rank" in the function "lapply" in R?

Tags: r, argument-passing, rank

R Version 2.11.1 32-bit on Windows 7

Now I get the code: `lapply(x, rank)`

but I want the "rank" to be: `ties.method="first"`

Comment: It's all in the help files...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As part of the optional argument `...`: `lapply(x, rank, ties.method = "first")`.

See `?lapply` for details.